# Strange behavior with empty string on Switch statement

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a parent child relationship between customers and I would like to use the PATH function to identify all the ancestors of a customer.  Sometimes the parent is not provided, and I have an empty string, so I'm using a SWITCH statement to execute the PATH function only if the parent and child are different.  At least that is my intention.  Here is the calculated column:

```
    SWITCH(
        Customer[ParentAccount],
        BLANK(), Customer[Account],
        "", Customer[Account], -- required, empty string does not equate to a blank
        Customer[Account], Customer\[Account\],
        PATH(
            Customer[Account],
            Customer[ParentAccount]
        )
    )
```

The above results in an error ("The value '' in 'Customer'[ParentAccount] must also exist in 'Customer'[Account]. Please add the missing data and try again.").

However, if I were to replace the PATH function with a simple string like "Other", the switch statement works!

The switch [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax) explicitly says "The order of conditions matters. As soon as one value matches, the corresponding result is returned, and other subsequent values aren’t evaluated."

So my question is why is the SWITCH statement above giving an error and apparently evaluating the PATH function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally had to break this into two steps.  First I created a column that provided a parent account that was guaranteed not to have any blanks:

```
ParentWithNoBlanks = 
    SWITCH(
        Customer[ParentAccount],
        BLANK(), Customer[Account],
        "", Customer[Account],
        Customer[Account], Customer[Account],
        Customer[ParentAccount]
    )
```

Then I modified my original statement to just calculate the PATH and the new column:

```
CustomerHeirarchy = 
    PATH(
        Customer[Account], 
        Customer[ParentWithNoBlanks]
    )
```